# Unable to access localhost - 403 forbidden

Tags: php, apache, localhost, lamp, http-status-code-403

I am able to access some areas of the localhost but cannot access others
for example,

- I can access  `localhost/index.php`, `localhost/somefolder/`
- but not `localhost/somefolder/anotherfolder`

I am also unable to `include` any file from inside `anotherfolder` in php because it says `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

I have `chmod -R 755 www` but still unable to access sub directories

what may be the cause?

Comment: Did you change the permissions for the folder and the files? I remember some case where I changed the permission for the files, but the folder still wouldn't allow the access.

Comment: @gkaykck I don't believe it's anything to do with the code since I am trying to access these locations from the browser my self

Comment: @Ahatius I did `chmod -R 755 www` which should change files and folders recursively.

Comment: What does the Apache log (e.g. `/var/log/httpd/error_log`) say?

Comment: @nico i checked `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and I got `Directory index forbidden by Options directive`

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess in any of those directories? If you do, could you post them here? It sounds like there might be a Apache configuration in either the httpd.conf or an .htaccess that could be causing the issue.

Comment: Add `Indexes` in the directory `Options` defined in `/etc/conf/httpd/httpd.conf` if you want to enable directory listing for that directory, then restart Apache `service httpd restart`.

Comment: I do not have a .htaccess in any of my folders but, `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` has only `ServerName localhost` inside it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see if you have SELinux running on that machine. Then do a ls -alZ on the directories you can view and the ones you can't. Chances are if you have SELinux enabled, the security group for the directory you can not view in is not set to the http security group. I believe it should be something to the effect of `system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t`.

Check to see if SELinux is enabled on your system in `/etc/selinux/config`. If it is, go to the directory that you are having trouble with and type: `chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t <directory name>`. That will add the httpd content security flag to that directory and everything under it, allowing apache to access it.

Comment: I don't have the directory: `/etc/selinux` so I'm guessing I don't have SELinux on my machine.

Comment: Just for reference: a [nice article about SELinux configuration](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/practical-selinux-for-the-beginner-contexts-and-labels/2458)

Answer (score 2):

If there is no 'index.html' (or index.php) in your folders you cannot reach them without exposing your directories to public. That should be disabled by default, but for your include problem i need some code and directory tree.